# c# Pub-Sub patron

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mvvm

Estoy intentando utilizar el patrón Pub-Sub para comunicar los ViewModels de mi aplicación, pero algo debo estar haciendo mal, ya que no consigo que se disparen los eventos.

La clase con el código para manejar los eventos es esta:

```
    namespace App.Services
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public delegate void MessengerEventHandler<T>(object sender, MessengerEventArgs<T> args);

    public class MessengerEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
    {
        public T Item { get; set; }
        public MessengerEventArgs(T item)
        {
            Item = item;
        }
    }

    public enum MessengerType
    {
        NavigateToBalanceView
    }

    public static class Messenger<T>
    {
        private static Dictionary<MessengerType, MessengerEventHandler<T>> events = new Dictionary<MessengerType, MessengerEventHandler<T>>();

        public static void AddEvent(MessengerType name, MessengerEventHandler<T> handler)
        {
            if (!events.ContainsKey(name))
                events.Add(name, handler);
        }

        public static void RaiseEvent(MessengerType name, object sender, MessengerEventArgs<T> args)
        {
            if (events.ContainsKey(name) && events[name] != null)
                events[name](sender, args);
        }

        public static void RegisterEvent(MessengerType name, MessengerEventHandler<T> handler)
        {
            if (events.ContainsKey(name))
                events[name] += handler;
        }
    }
}
```

La implementación la tengo en el HomeViewModel para agregar un evento así:

```
namespace App.ViewModels
{
    using Base;
    using Models.DAL;
    using Services;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

    public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public event MessengerEventHandler<object> NavigateToBalanceViewHandler;

        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            Messenger<object>.AddEvent(MessengerType.NavigateToBalanceView, NavigateToBalanceViewHandler);
        }

        private decimal balance;
        public decimal Balance
        {
            get { return balance; }
            set { balance = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public override Task OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override Task OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            using (var db = new Context())
            {
                var bal = db.Balance.FirstOrDefault();
                if (bal == null)
                {
                    Messenger<object>.RaiseEvent(MessengerType.NavigateToBalanceView, this,
                        new MessengerEventArgs<object>(typeof(BalanceViewModel)));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

y en el MainViewModel para registrar el evento,´así:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Messenger<object>.RegisterEvent(MessengerType.NavigateToBalanceView, NavigateToBalanceViewHandler);
        }

        private void NavigateToBalanceViewHandler(object sender, MessengerEventArgs<object> args)
        {

        }
}
```

Cuando se añade el evento desde el HomeViewModel, registra correctamente en el listado, pero siempre con el manejador, "MessengerEventHandler" con valor nulo, por lo que al disparar el evento, encuentra el tipo, pero el valor siempre es nulo.

¿Alguna pista por dónde buscar o qué revisar?

Muchas gracias.

Edito, me estoy basando en el modelo PubSub que encontré aquí:

[Comunicación entre ViewModels](http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/07/pub-sub-observer-pattern-in-mvvm.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que no desarrolles tú todo el patrón Pub-Sub en tu aplicación, ya que hay frameworks que ya lo tienen desarrollado y te quitan muchísimo trabajo y te facilitan las cosas. Yo utilizo Prism, que tiene un desarrollo PubSub que funciona a la perfección y además tiene una comunidad bastante amplia donde te solucionan todas las dudas (https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Events/PubSubEvent.cs)

Te dejo el enlace del paquete NuGet por si quieres echarle un vistazo: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Para comunicar los ViewModels de tu aplicación llamando los métodos y usando los atributos públicos entre ellos, puedes declararlos como un atributo de alcance público y definiéndolo como estático (como se muestra en el siguiente código con el ViewModel llamado MainViewModel) en la clase principal del proyecto (App.xaml.cs), es importante que inicialices el ViewModel dentro del constructor de esta misma clase.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string User;
    public static MainViewModel MainViewModel;

    public App()
    {
        MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

        InitializeComponent();
        FlowListView.Init();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.Main.MainPage()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#002f6c") };
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
```

Después de hacer esto, ya puedes acceder a los métodos y las propiedades del ViewModel desde cualquier otro ViewModel o CodeBehind por medio del llamado a los atributos de la clase principal (App.xaml.cs) de la siguiente forma:

```
public partial class ColorOptionsDialog : PopupPage
{
    public ColorOptionsDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = App.MainViewModel;
    }

    async void ColorsList_FlowItemTapped(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Color colorSelected = (Color)e.Item;
        App.MainViewModel.Color = colorSelected;
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @David, considere cambiar las imágenes donde aparece el código por el código para facilitar la copia y reproducción del mismo.